# reference for weighted blow-up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $(0\in X)$ be a germ of a normal 3-fold with a singular point $0$
(over $\mathbb{C}$).
We think of $X$ as a small neighborhood of $0$ (for studying singularity).

If we can think $X$ as a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^4$ defined by an equation 
$$
f(t,x,y,z)=t^2+g_4(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{C}[[t,x,y,z]], \  \ \ mult_0(g_4)\ge 4,
$$
then what is the weighted blow-up $Y:=WBl_0X\to X$ of $X$ at $0$ with weights $w(t,x,y,z)=(2,1,1,1)$? What is a exceptional divisor? and what...?
I don't know even basic things about weighted blow-up. So I want to know about weighted blow-up concretely. But I couldn't find a good reference.

Does anyone know a good reference for weighted blow-up?

Comment: In this generality, I'm not sure that much can be said besides that you are blowing up a subscheme.  What examples have you already tried?